# Mongodb distinct query with contains query

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo collection *User* which contains data like:-

```
{
 id : 1,
 name : "gaurav",
 skills  : "C++ HTML CSS"
}
```

when I am searching for all users that have *C++* skill in it with the following query I am getting correct results as expected

```
db.user.find({skills:{contains:"C++"}});
```

But when I am searching all the unique names from the user using the same condition I m not getting any desired result

```
db.user.distinct('name',{skills:{contains:"C++"}});
```

Can anyone help me with what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "contains" is not a valid keyword for MongoDB queries. You need **`$regex`** which submits a general "regular expression" statement matching the [pcre](http://www.pcre.org/) specifications:

```js
db.user.distinct( "name", { "skills": { "$regex": "C\+\+" } })
```

If using JavaScript as you language then this is also safe:

```js
db.user.distinct( "name", { "skills": /C\+\+/ })
```

To determine if the string "C++" occurred somewhere within the string value of the field being tested. The `+` character is reserved in "regex" operations and therefore you need to escape it with a `\` char as the standard escaping mechanism.

On your data this is the result:

```js
db.user.distinct( "name", { "skills": { "$regex": "C\+\+" } })
[ "gaurav" ]
```

Comment: @gauravjoshi Why not? It matches the data you posted and works for me.

Comment: But when I am running it with actual collection I m still getting no results

Comment: @gauravjoshi Probaly because the actual data in your collection **does not match** what you posted in your question. We answer questions here and don't use divine intervention to somehow magically determine what data you have that is not the same as what you presented. Perhaps this is something as stupid as the skills actually being in "lowercase" for which you do `{ "$regex": "C\+\+", "$options": "i" }` instead. Otherwise you don't have data that matches the the condition. Not my problem. Show your data you expect to match. Edit your question. I provide an answer based on the dat you provide.

Comment: Thanks this was the missing part "$options": "i"

Comment: @gauravjoshi Word of advice. If you are intending to store "skills" like this in a database 1. Use an array. 2. Keep the case common, either uppercase or lowercase. There are good notes on the referenced `$regex` documentation page that tell you why case insensitive matches are a bad thing for MongoDB queries with indexes.

Comment: BTW. I also rolled back your edits to your question after answers were submitted. Please do not do that again in future as you are confusing the context in which the answers provided are given.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use REGEX like below query

```
db.user.distinct("name",{"skills":{"$regex":"C++.*"}})
```

Comment: Sorry but the `+` is a reserved character in "pcre" which is the library used. This is not a valid regex.

Comment: @gauravjoshi Of course it doesn't work. Thats why I left the comment.